# How to make Python class constructor return an already existing object (pointing to the same object)?

Tags: python, class, object, constructor, magic-methods

I'm writing a class called Position, something like Python's Small Integer Constant Pool:

```
class Position:
    """Takes 2 args: x, and y. If coordinate are equal, make them pointing to the same object"""

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __new__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        import gc
        for obj in gc.get_objects():
            if isinstance(obj, eval(self.__qualname__)):  # Won't work cause arg 2 is a string, not a type name
                if obj.x == self.x and obj.y == self.y:
                    return obj
        return super(Position, self).__new__(self, *args, **kwargs)  # Have no idea what to write

p1 = Position(1, 2)
p2 = Position(2, 3)
p3 = Position(1, 2)

print(p1 is p2, p2 is p3, p1 is p3)  # Should print False, False, True
```

Rewriting **hash** and **eq** won't work when using `is` to compare.

I want my class to be something like:

```
a = 1
b = 1
print(a is b)  # True
```

Comment: You're making this more complicated than it needs to be.  You just want a dict mapping (x, y) tuples to your existing objects - or weak references to your existing objects if you want them to be garbage-collectable.

Comment: This implementation is absurdly inefficient, and also not threadsafe. Also, Python does not promise that small integers will be represented by the same object, and [small integers are in fact *not* always represented by the same object](https://ideone.com/y2pUJR).

Comment: "Rewriting `__hash__` and `__eq__` won't work when using `is` to compare." - the solution to that is to *not use `is`*. Use `==`.

Comment: Please pay attention to the efficiency argument.  Remember that each object only uses the space for its data (the functions are amortized over all instances).  For a small object like this, what you're doing is ridiculous.  Searching through the list of ALL objects just to save a dozen or two bytes is silly.

Answer (score 2):

You can't rely on the garbage collector list of all existing objects for this, and much less on a linear search of all objects.

Simply keep your objects in a registry where you can find then back.

You can use WeakValues dictionary so that if there is no reference left to anyone of your objects it is discarded. (Just use a plain dictionary if you want each one to remain created, even if it is no longer in use):

```
from weakref import WeakValueDictionary


class Position:
    """Takes 2 args: x, and y. If coordinate are equal, make them pointing to the same object"""
    _registry = WeakValueDictionary()

    def __new__(cls, x, y):
        if (x,y) in cls._registry:
            return cls._registry[x,y]
        instance = super().__new__(cls)  # don't pass extra *args and **kwargs to obj.__new__
        cls._registry[x,y] = instance
        return instance

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if hasattr(self, "x"):  # avoid running init twice if the attribute is already set
            return
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


p1 = Position(1, 2)
p2 = Position(2, 3)
p3 = Position(1, 2)
```

in this scenario p1 == p3 evaluates to True

Comment: Note that this is not thread-safe. If multiple threads create instances of Position at the same time, some of them may see corrupt, partially-initialized Position instances, and some Position instances may be initialized twice.

Comment: not all answers have to be "kernel level production ready". But yes, using a lock or other mechanism there is needed if this code will be used in a multi-threading contest - but it would work as it should under asyncio.  Multiprocessing needs a different data-structure to keep a shared result, and so on.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will look at how refrence works in python!